# Null conditional operator with nullable DateTimeOffset

Tags: c#, .net, c#-6.0, datetimeoffset, null-conditional-operator

**Environment:** Visual Studio 2015

**TimeZone:**: UTC + 7:00, Bangkok

**Issue**: On DateTimeOffset nullable varialbe (DateTimeOffset?), the use of Null Conditional operator results in exception i.e. it still calls the method even if the value is NULL i.e. (value as DateTimeOffset?)?.ToLocalTime(), it calls the ToLocalTime and results in exception.

**Query**: I can resolve it by not using the Null conditional operator or using the GetValueOrDefault instead of the operator but I want to understand why it resutls in exception with all UTC + TimeZones, it works well with UTC - TimeZones

**Code:**

```
var dateTimeMinimum = DateTime.MinValue;
    var value = (object)dateTimeMinimum; // Mimic the WPF converter behavior
    var a1 = value as DateTimeOffset?; // This works
    if (a1 != null)// This works as it won't execute the code in the 'if'loop
    {
        var b1 = (a1 as DateTimeOffset?)?.ToLocalTime();
    }

var dto = (value as DateTimeOffset?)?.ToLocalTime() ?? (DateTime)value;// This breaks with following exception
```

[image]

**EDIT**:

I understand there are many ways to fix the code i.e.

```
    DateTime dateTimeMinimum = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.MinValue, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

Here's my query though, when I do not use the null conditional operator

```
var a1 = value as DateTimeOffset?;
```

It does not result in exception. Is it because the null conditional operator unwraps the variable per following blog

http://www.ninjacrab.com/2016/09/11/c-how-the-null-conditional-operator-works-with-nullable-types/

I am more interested in understanding why it breaks when I use null conditional operator and works when I simple cast if using the 'as' operator without using the DateTimeKind.Utc

**EDIT2**:

This is the constructor of DateTimeOffset (.NET framework code) and it breaks at ValidateOffset method. **Source** - http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetimeoffset.cs,68b4bb83ce8d1c31

```
 // Constructs a DateTimeOffset from a DateTime. For Local and Unspecified kinds,
        // extracts the local offset. For UTC, creates a UTC instance with a zero offset.
        public DateTimeOffset(DateTime dateTime) {
            TimeSpan offset;
            if (dateTime.Kind != DateTimeKind.Utc) {
                // Local and Unspecified are both treated as Local
                offset = TimeZoneInfo.GetLocalUtcOffset(dateTime, TimeZoneInfoOptions.NoThrowOnInvalidTime);
            }
            else {            
                offset = new TimeSpan(0);
            }
            m_offsetMinutes = ValidateOffset(offset);
            m_dateTime = ValidateDate(dateTime, offset);
        }
```

Comment: what is the value of the offset when that exception was thrown? The error message seems to suggest that the resultant year was either less than 0 or greater than 10K

Comment: DateTime.MinValue

Comment: that is the value of the offset?

Comment: There is no offset value as I'm using DateTime value. The issue is if the value is NULL, it should not call ToLocalTime method as it uses the NULL CONDITIONAL OPERATOR

Comment: You are using an offset, so there is clearly an offset value. The issue is not that the offset is null, it is that it is not of an allowable value.

Comment: Why are you doing a `DateTime` as `DateTimeOffset`? That always produce `null`, at least in my case.

Comment: @WPF_Learn, you are not getting a null reference exception, you are getting an out of range one, so the null value is not what's causing your issue.

Comment: @Andrew, I'm using the Null conditional operator which means it should not even call the ToLocalTime method which results in out of range exception. See variable a1 in my code, if that works than null conditional operator should work too instead of resulting in out of range exception

Comment: Please care to put your comments when giving negative vote for the question.

Comment: Again, @WPF_Learn, `value as DateTimeOffset?` **is not a valid conversion, it will always give you null, do not use that**. The `as` operator has the feature of not throwing exceptions when it's invalid, so that's why you get a `null` there. If you replace that with `var a1 = (DateTimeOffset?)value`, you will get the corresponding `System.InvalidCastException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the minimum date is at UTC 0, so if you want that **but with a positive UTC**, that means that at UTC 0 it will be earlier than the minimum possible `DateTime`.

To put it simply, you can't create this (minimum date UTC +1):

```
new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.MinValue, new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0))
```

Because this would create a `DateTimeOffset` for Dec 31st **-0001** 11:00PM UTC.

The exception occurs exactly here:

```
var dto = <something null> ?? (DateTime)value;
```

As `dto` is inferred as `DateTimeOffset`, there you are doing `(DateTimeOffset)(DateTime)value`, and then is when the exception is thrown. That cast tries to create the negative date, which can't be represented.

Try this code to confirm that the issue is **not related** to a null variable:

```
var dateTimeMinimum = DateTime.MinValue;
var value = (object)dateTimeMinimum; // Mimic the WPF converter behavior
DateTimeOffset dto = (DateTime)value;
```

---

**UPDATE**

As you still don't believe me, try this:

```
var dto = (value as DateTimeOffset?)?.ToLocalTime() ?? new DateTimeOffset();
```

This won't fail. Why? Because `ToLocalTime` is **not being executed and never was**, and what failed all this time was what I told you, the cast from minimum `DateTime` to `DateTimeOffset` with positive timezone.

---

BTW, you can't just convert a `DateTime` to a `DateTimeOffset?` with the `as` operator; that will always return null. That operator is for compatible clases.

In the end, even fixing this, I think your code is too difficult to understand and maintain. What are you exactly trying to do here?

Comment: Thats what I want a NULL value and for that I'm using Null conditional operator. If that is Null, I'm trying to parse it to DateTime.

Comment: var dto = (value as DateTimeOffset?)?.ToLocalTime() ?? (DateTime)value;

Comment: But it's not null, you get an exception... UTC Minimum DateTime converted to LocalTime (UTC +7) throws that exception. No null problem related.

Comment: Following works:var dateTimeMinimum = DateTime.MinValue;
    var value = (object)dateTimeMinimum; // Mimic the WPF converter behavior
    var a1 = value as DateTimeOffset?; // This works

Comment: When I do not use the Null conditional operator, it doesn't result in exception. See the code till, variable a1 in my code.

Comment: @WPF_Learn, please, try to understand what I am explaining to you. You insist on the null thing but **it's not the issue**. Please, check the update that I added to my answer. Hopefully that will make you realize what's going on.

Comment: I guess this means you understood the issue and managed to make it work? :)

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the nullable operator.

This will cause the same error:

```
var dto2 = new DateTimeOffset(dateTimeMinimum);
```

The offset is too big when using DateTime.Min, If you change it to DateTime.Now, your code will work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If you see the a1 variable in my code, it results in NULL value and then execution won't enter if block. Same way if the "value" variable is cast to DateTimeOffset?, it should be NULL, it should not result in exception.

Comment: The as operator in this case will always return NULL because you are trying to convert between DateTime and DateTimeOffset which are unrelated classes, while the NULL operator tries to get the value. I'm not that familiar with "behind the scene" of Roslyn null operator but I believe your line acts like explicit cast